# Load a Page that is protected by CSP

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, content-security-policy

I want to scrap Images from midjourney.com I had a perfectly working script that can do this but now my requests get blocked. I get a 403 ( Forbidden ) as response. To validate my code I converted the coped the request to the main page out off my Browser and converted it in to a script that dose the same request

My Guess is that this is a new Content Security Policy too prevent loading the site outside off a Browser. Has anyone a idea to get around this?

I would really appreciate some hints or ideas. Btw this is the test script:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'imageSize': 'medium',
    'imageLayout_2': 'hover',
    'getImageAspect': '2',
    'fullWidth': 'false',
    'showHoverIcons': 'true',
    '_dd_s': 'rum=0&expire=1687926962555',
    '__Host-next-auth.csrf-token': 'c19e3aa92427d9ade40721425bf5affb4955e52f766d0c2a8ca064d3ffef6d9c^%^7Cda294da6acc19312b0399c98e0148de068f41999f76145e15717bdcd3ee9f5c9',
    '__Secure-next-auth.callback-url': 'https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.midjourney.com',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Alt-Used': 'www.midjourney.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # 'Cookie': 'imageSize=medium; imageLayout_2=hover; getImageAspect=2; fullWidth=false; showHoverIcons=true; _dd_s=rum=0&expire=1687926962555; __Host-next-auth.csrf-token=c19e3aa92427d9ade40721425bf5affb4955e52f766d0c2a8ca064d3ffef6d9c^%^7Cda294da6acc19312b0399c98e0148de068f41999f76145e15717bdcd3ee9f5c9; __Secure-next-auth.callback-url=https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.midjourney.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.midjourney.com/home/?callbackUrl=^%^2Fapp^%^2F', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Load website with CSP

Comment: It's not likely to be caused by CSP as this is something implemented by the browser (just like CORS). Given that the returned status is a 403 (Forbidden) the chances are that there's a cookie or something that you're missing that is used to authenticate requests.

Answer (score 0):

CSP is protection mechanism that only works [inside of  browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#browser_compatibility), not in python scripts outside of the browser. It's the browser's role to read the headers of the incoming request and prevent the content from running/being shown to the user. If you run your script outside of the browser, the reason behind `403` response is likely not CSP.

I would advise to get a fresh values for `cookies` variable. Possibly some of the tokens in the `cookies` variable have expired and hence the 403.